# How to calculate a cumulative sum from the bottom up?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in PostgreSQL which yields:

```
itemorder   name    qty
  1          A       -20
  2          A2       350
  3          A        50
  4          A        -10
  5          A2       10
```

the `itemorder` column gives the correct order of rows as I expect to see. 
I need to pass over the rows from bottom to top and calculate a new column that has an initial value of `100` and does `+ qty` for each row of `A`.

```
itemorder   name    qty       modifyed_sum
  1          A       -20          120       / 140 + (-20)
  2          A2       350         140       / not A
  3          A        50          140       / 90 + 50
  4          A        -10         90        / 100 +  (-10)
  5          A2       10          100       / not A
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I feel that it might help to also show the original query and sample data.

Comment: The original query is irrelevent this is what it yeilds. you can use` from 'X'` i'll know how to convert it to draw the data from the query.

Comment: Nope.  We might not need to use the original query as you had it.  But in any case @VR46 licked your question in record time.

Comment: Your Postgres version is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 100+ Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN qty ELSE 0 END)OVER(ORDER BY itemorder DESC) as modifyed_sum,
       qty,
       name,
       itemorder
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY itemorder ASC
```

Another way

```
SELECT 100 + (SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN b.name = 'a' THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)
              FROM   yourtable  b
              WHERE  a.itemorder <= b.itemorder),
       qty,
       name,
       itemorder
FROM   yourtable a
ORDER  BY itemorder ASC
```

Comment: How can you use IF in a query?

Comment: @200_success - yeah it is `ASC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemorder
     , name
     , qty
     , 100 + SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'A' THEN qty ELSE 0 END)
             OVER (ORDER BY itemorder ASC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS modifyed_sum
    FROM thetable
    ORDER BY itemorder;
```

The `ROWS BETWEEN …` feature is [a value expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html) to be used in a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).